# Small Flickering spots on the screen

Tags: display, graphics-card

my dog just threw a fit in my room, and it looks like a little bit of water might have spilled on my computer.

When I first tried to turn my computer The monitor wouldn't turn on, and then after a bit the computer seemed to shut down and attempt to restart itself whenever I attempted to turn it on.

After about an hour of letting my computer sit with the case Open, and pulling out my hard drives, ram, and graphics card, and plugging them back in, I attempted to start my computer again, and it worked like normal(that was 30 minutes ago), except for one thing.

every once in a while these small black spots will appear on my screen.  They're about 2 millimeters high, and about half a centimeter wide.

What is the likely cause?  Could there be a connection issue between my graphics card and my PC?

did I damage my graphics card in some way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could be a kind of liquid damage. Imagine some little drops of liquid are still there or they dried, vaporized just water from them, but left shorting (new current leading tracks). If the affected pins are data signals, it could make some bits in the video data flow to constant 0 or 1, to a pattern view, sort of, XXX1XXXX, or XXXXX0XX, or any other, which would be seen like a spots at monitor.

You are recommend to make dry your video card, chips on it, connector, slot at Mainboard, at least, but ideally all parts with heating fan, simply hot air (don't play with that professional stuff for soldering with hot air - it's too much). After this, clean again with spirit (or vodka) all dirtiness and suspected places. Leave it to dry for a little while.

Give it a try again.

Comment: And please do not power this stuff when it is wet or even damp :-) it does electrolisis , galvanic changes , and carbon trails.  It is better to wait then to lose it completly.